# Script cannot find attributes of an appended html element

Tags: javascript, html

It outputs undefined for both. It should output lpoop and /poop. No errors are given

```js
function add() {
  console.log("add")
  var l = document.createElement("img")
  l.setAttribute("src", "/poop")
  l.src = "/poop"
  l.setAttribute("class", "l")
  l.className = "lpoop"
  document.getElementById("b").appendChild(l)
}

function find() {
  console.log("find");
  const elm = document.getElementById("b").firstChild;
  console.log(elm.className);
  console.log(elm.src);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">
  hi
</button>
<button onclick="find()">
find
</button>

<div id="b">

</div>
```

If there is any more detail you want pls comment.

Comment: The problem is that the first child of `#b` is not the image that you've created, it is a text node, to get the image use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`.

Comment: Whitespace between elements is considered text nodes. If there is a whitespace before "img" element, the result will be "undefined".

Comment: @MORÈ your changes have removed the problem.

Comment: @MORÈ No need, I've made an edit myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function add() {
  console.log("add")
  var l = document.createElement("img")
  l.setAttribute("src", "/poop")
  l.setAttribute("class", "l")
  document.getElementById("b").appendChild(l)
}

function find() {
  console.log("find");
  const elm = document.getElementById("b").firstChild;
  console.log(elm.getAttribute("src"));
  console.log(elm.getAttribute("class"));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">
  hi
</button>
<button onclick="find()">
find
</button>

<div id="b"></div>
```

When you use `elem.attr` it means that you are getting the JS Attribute of the element, not the HTML attribute.

The `.getAttribute()` function will get the HTML attribute.